# How to create regular expression for phone numbers in java android?

Tags: java, android, regex

I know this kind of question is not common but will appreciate if anybody could help me. 
I'm trying to parse a long string which contains phone numbers. there are totally 3 kind of numbers, here are just example of these 3 :
+603333332222
00603333332222
03333332222

suppose we have string like this :
+603333332222006033333322220333333222200603333332222+603333332222

now all i want is to separate this long string into single strings that matches the pattern , so the output would be :

+603333332222,00603333332222,03333332222,00603333332222,+603333332222

if its difficult to answer or there is good source of learning this kind of a thing please help me.

thanks

UPDATE :

there are 3 kind of regulars :

1. +60
2. 0060
3. 06

and the length is always as this:

1. 13
2. 14
3. 11

Comment: Try to define what is so regular about numbers you want to find/separate. Then explain what is stopping you from writing your regex which will describe these properties.

Comment: i have edited my question. you can find it on UPDATE section. @Pshemo

Comment: In other words you want to *find* string which starts with `+60` OR `0060` OR `06` and has exactly 10 digits after it?

Comment: If yes, then here are some hints: `OR` operator is represented by `|`; since `+` is special you need to escape it, so regex representing it can look like `\+` or `[+]`; to group some expressions you need to wrap them with parenthesis. So try to use something like `(X|Y|Z)end`.

Comment: yes exactly , its the same for first two numbers , but is different for last one , means last one is 9 digit after 06. and the others are 10 correct @Pshemo

Comment: I see in your example `03333332222` as result. It doesn't start with neither of prefixes specified by you. Is it correct phone number or should it be skipped?

Comment: thats my mistake, correct is 06333332222 @Pshemo

Comment: So you want to find ((`+60` OR `0060`) and 10 digits after it) OR (`06` and 9 digits after it). Try to write it as regex.

Comment: any example how to achieve this? @Pshemo

Comment: I gave you description which practically writes regex itself. Is there some part which is unclear? Are you familiar with regex basics? Have you used it in Java?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126474/discussion-between-mahdi-giveie-and-pshemo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Regex will probably not be the best way, as Rippr pointed out, but it might still work. You should begin by writing the 3 regexes (one for each format) and then combine them with OR - maybe something like this.

You'll still be annoyed if there are zeros or 0060 in the 10 digits.

`(0060|\+60|0)[0-9]{10}`

You can, however, parse the string with an if/else tree like this :

```
If +60 at start of the remainings of the string then then  
   format is +60[10 digits number]
   Store this phone number somewhere and processus the remainings char of the string
If 0060 at start of the remainings of the string then
  format is 0060[10 digits number]
  Store the number and continue proccessing
Else
  Format is 0[10 digits number]
  Store it and process the rest
```

Or parse the string with the given regex preceded with a `^` and rip out of it each first number identifiés and loop

Comment: Thanks, in the post (backskash +) only showed +, backskash needed to be escaped there

Comment: To avoid problem with skipping \ or < > in your post try to wrap it in code section (`{}` icon in editor). This should print all characters from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SubString](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) to separate the numbers which start with the +. As for the other 2, it's quite impossible... I mean, given:

1234567890123456789012345

How can you tell if it's 12345678901 and 23456789012345

or 12345678901234 and 56789012345?